# Does TrueType core fonts for the Web (included in ubuntu-restricted-extras) share data with Microsoft?

Tags: fonts, microsoft

It has a license agreement, which I've never seen when installing something using apt, so I'm wondering if it also has a privacy policy or anything?

Comment: Fonts are just data files. It cannot share anything with anyone.

Comment: It's a package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) installed using apt, not a data file.

Comment: The license agreement is just about sharing/distribution/use of the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, as it can be seen on the enclosed screenshot, basically contains only a script `/usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts`, a list of font files to download (`/usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer`) and documentation files. The font files are downloaded from SourceForge (not even from Microsoft), and uncompressed by the aforementioned script into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts` directory.

Although the font files themselves are compressed to `.exe` format, they are just self-extracting archives, and because `.exe` files obviously can't run on Linux, they are uncompressed using an external tool (`cabextract`) anyway.

So there's no place where any data could be shared with Microsoft.

[image]